# How can I get the lost events when a java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW occur

Tags: java, nio, watchservice

I am busy writing a Java application which uses the `java.nio.file.WatchService`.

```
watchKey = watchService.take();

for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
// Handle the events
}

watchKey.reset();
```

The event are polled and handled correctly.

The problem comes in the next time I call `watchService.take()`

During the processing of the events more event happened so the first event is of type `StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW`.

How do I get hold of these events or stop events from being lost?
It is important that I do not loose any events.

Comment: I think this might be a Java 1.7.0_09-b05 bug. If I use jpathwatch, it does not loose the events.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is to fetch events in one thread but process them in another one. For example you can use an `Executor` obtained by `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor` and dispatch event processing tasks to it.

Comment: I am doing it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Created a pool of 10 consumers taking from the watchService. This way no events are lost.